# rails missing console and generate commands on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Using "***rails server***" and "***rails new***" work normally

However no other commands are recognized, such as "***rails console***" and "***rails generate***" --- the rails help is displayed.

This is with Rails 3.2.1 + Ruby 1.9.2 & 1.9.3

I tried 3 pre-packaged installations, on Windows 7 64bit.  Everything else appears to be working

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have 2 versions of ruby installed?

Answer (score 2):

"rails console" and "rails generate", ect. must be run in a folder with standard gems installed, i.e. created with "rails new [location]"